# GitHub Action pull request failing

Tags: github-actions

My GitHub Action is failing on the final step, creating a pull request.
[image]

[image]

Below is the section of my yml file that is failing.

```
 pull-request:
     needs: regression-tests
     name: Development to Master
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v2
       name: checkout
     - uses: repo-sync/pull-request@v2
       name: pull-request
       with:
         destination_branch: "master"
         pr_title: "Pulling ${{ github.ref }} into master"
         pr_body: "*An automated PR test*"
         pr_reviewer: "Kev"
         pr_draft: true         
         github_token: ${{ secrets.PullRequest }}
```

And this is what I see in the log

> ```
> 2021-05-26T10:25:10.0613353Z ##[section]Starting: Request a runner to run this job
> 2021-05-26T10:25:10.4927450Z Can't find any online and idle self-hosted runner in current repository that matches the required
> ```
>
> labels: 'ubuntu-latest'
> 2021-05-26T10:25:10.4927569Z Can't find any online and idle self-hosted runner in current repository's account/organization that
> matches the required labels: 'ubuntu-latest'
> 2021-05-26T10:25:10.4928148Z Found online and idle hosted runner in current repository's account/organization that matches the required
> labels: 'ubuntu-latest'
> 2021-05-26T10:25:10.6935866Z ##[section]Finishing: Request a runner to run this job
> 2021-05-26T10:25:18.9831794Z Current runner version: '2.278.0'
> 2021-05-26T10:25:18.9861037Z ##[group]Operating System
> 2021-05-26T10:25:18.9862046Z Ubuntu
> 2021-05-26T10:25:18.9862461Z 20.04.2
> 2021-05-26T10:25:18.9862889Z LTS
> 2021-05-26T10:25:18.9863336Z ##[endgroup]
> 2021-05-26T10:25:18.9864044Z ##[group]Virtual Environment
> 2021-05-26T10:25:18.9864687Z Environment: ubuntu-20.04
> 2021-05-26T10:25:18.9865181Z Version: 20210524.1
> 2021-05-26T10:25:18.9866149Z Included Software: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/ubuntu20/20210524.1/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-README.md
> 2021-05-26T10:25:18.9867437Z Image Release: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/releases/tag/ubuntu20%2F20210524.1

Any thoughts please on what the issue could be?

Comment: Could this be something related to your issue, https://github.community/t/action-fails-after-20-minutes-without-log/18432/2? In the action run UI, you should see device space error message?

Comment: Hi, not sure how that relates to my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This edited code now works

```
 pull-request:
      needs: regression-tests
      name: Github Pull Request
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: pull-request
        uses: repo-sync/pull-request@v2
        with:
          destination_branch: "master"
          pr_title: "Pulling ${{ github.ref }} into master"
          pr_body: " *An automated PR test*"
          pr_reviewer: "Kev"
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```